# Logging a diff of updated model in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Our team is trying to implement a logging solution for Django's Admin, where we would know not just which fields have been changed in latest CRUD operation on a specific model, but also the values that have changed - in short, along history we would also like a diff.

We tried the post_save hook/override the save method, but that requires the overriding on every single model.

EDIT: Forgot an important detail, we require this only for actions done via Django's Admin, not the rest of the code/API, ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you look into the package `django-simple-history`?

It has an [Admin integration](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html).

> This will replace the history object page on the admin site and allow
> viewing and reverting to previous model versions. Changes made in
> admin change forms will also accurately note the user who made the
> change.